# How to replace successive occurrences of characters in a file by the number

Tags: c, string, file, pointers, file-descriptor

In my code, I successfully opened the file, but now I don't understand how to perform a loop using the read() function, to get all the characters in `file1`. I set a buffer of size 8, but the file contents are more.

Thanks. Also please help me do this using syscalls like that

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not add C prefix to titles. That is the purpose of tags.

Comment: Just FYI, this is called [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused between a `char` and a pointer to a `char`:

```
char *buffer[4096];
```

Is an array of pointers to chars, an is supposed to hold pointers, not `chars`. What you want is an array of `char`:

```
char buffer[4096];
```

Now when you add the `\0` you will get a compiler error. This also means that it contains a string, meaning you use the `%s` conversion for `printf` to print it, no loop involved, just do:

```
printf("%s", buffer);
```

Also, do your `read` like this (again no loop needed):

```
ssize_t count = read(fd1, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1);
if(count < 0)
    return -1;
```

This will read up to 4095 bytes into your array, depending on the size of the file. This leaves room for your `\0`.

So to make sure you read all your file, do something like:

```
ssize_t count;
while((count = read(fd1, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1)) != 0)
{
    if(count < 0)
        return -1;

    buffer[count] = '\0';
    printf("%s", buffer);

    // Do your processing here
}
```

The idea is to read a chunk from the file, then process it as required, then read another chunk etc. When the end of the file is reached, `read` will return `0` and your processing will stop.

An equivalent way to do this loop, which may be easier to understand is:

```
ssize_t count = read(fd1, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1);
while(count != 0)
{
    // .....

    count = read(fd1, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1);
}
```

This makes it more clear that you are looping until `count` is zero. The trick I have used is to take the `count = read(...)` part and put it inside the parentheses. The result of evaluating what is inside the parentheses `(count = read(...))`, is the result of the assignment (ie what gets assigned to `count`, which is the result of `read`). Putting this inside `while` statement means the part in parentheses gets evaluated first (ie it does the `read` and assigns `count`). The the result of the assignment (ie `count`) then gets checked to see if it is zero.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199820/discussion-on-answer-by-graeme-how-to-replace-successive-occurrences-of-characte).